# Compass sprite position-x

Tags: compass-sass, css-sprites, background-position

I'm using the [compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-position) sprite helpers to position an icon and it works on the y axis, but it's positioned at 0 on the x axis. Now I could set the x offset to a fixed value, but I'd rather have it set to "right".

This is my code now:

```
background: {
  url: sprite-url($icons-sprite);
  repeat: no-repeat;
  position: sprite-position($icons-sprite, nav-active);
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve (pseudo-code):

```
background: {
  url: sprite-url($icons-sprite);
  repeat: no-repeat;
  position: right sprite-position-y($icons-sprite, nav-active);
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Automatic sprites

Before creating the sprite map, you must specify the sprite engine you want to have the sprite on the right side of the sprite map (see [the documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/customization-options/) for further information):

```
$icons-nav-active-position: 100%;
@import "icons/*.png";
```

Then call the function `sprite-position()` as the usual:

```
position: sprite-position($icons-sprite, nav-active);
```

### Manual sprites

When you call `sprite-map()`, you must pass the argument `$<map>-<sprite>-position: 100%` (where `<map>` represents the folder name that contains your sprites):

```
$icons-sprite: sprite-map("icons/*.png", $icons-nav-active-position: 100%);
background: {
  url: sprite-url($icons-sprite);
  repeat: no-repeat;
  position: sprite-position($icons-sprite, nav-active);
}
```

*Note 1:* you can pass the argument `$position: 100%` to set the position for all the sprites.
*Note 2:* **before** Compass 0.12.1, the arguments to pass to `sprite-map()` does not start with `<map>-`. See [the issue 828](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/828).

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, I'm generating the sprite with sprite-map(). Is there a way to do this manually?